# PHP8.0 connecting to MYSQL8.0 using SSL

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, mysqli

I'm trying to connect to my SQL database which is Google Cloud SQL, ofcourse through SSL because it goes through the internet. Connecting through Datagrip with the credentials and client certificates works.

I've tried multiple codes from the internet but it doesn't seem to be working.

My code:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);
try {
    $mysqli = mysqli_init();
    if (!$mysqli) {
        die("mysqli_init failed");
    }

    $mysqli->ssl_set($key,$certificate,$ca,null,null);
    if(!$mysqli->real_connect(  "<server>",
                                "<username>",
                                "<password>",
                                "<database>",
                                3306,
                                NULL,
                                MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT
                                ));

    return $mysqli;
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    $DatabaseAvailable = false;
    echo $e;
}
if (!$DatabaseAvailable) {
    ?><h1>Connection failed</h1><?php
    die();
}
```

I get the error: mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user(using password: YES)

Im not familiar with PDO, I've tried it but its not working.

### UPDATE

The stacktrace goes to row 87 witch is the line with the flag `MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL_DONT_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT`

I've tried this codes for the options:

```
ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $mysqli = mysqli_init(); if (!$mysqli) {die("mysqli_init failed");}
    mysqli_options ($mysqli, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
    $mysqli->ssl_set($key,$certificate,$ca,NULL,NULL);
    $mysqli->real_connect(  "<server>",
                                "<username>",
                                "<password>",
                                "<database>",
                                3306,
                                NULL,
                                MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);

    return $mysqli;
} catch (mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
    ?><h1>Connection failed</h1><?php
    echo $e;
}
```

Because in the first version the SSL wasn't enforced I think. This one doesn't work either, the error now gives: bad gateway

Comment: Based on the error message, it looks like the credentials (username/password) are wrong.

Comment: @M.Eriksson, I've checked the credentials and tried it with the root account and that doesn't work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution, the certificates were stored in a string. Strings can't hold a certificate. So I've got to do it differently. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).